# Google Charts tooltip in a LineChart

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, linechart

little problem with tooltips here.

So, I want to display tooltips on points in a LineChart but I always have an error

> All series on a given axis must be of the same data type

Here is my code, let me know if you have any ideas ..

```
data.addColumn('date','Date');
data.addColumn('number','Actual Value for x');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addColumn('number','Actual Value for y');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addColumn('number','Actual Value for z');
data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip'});
data.addColumn('number','Theoretical Value for x');
data.addColumn('number','Theoretical Value for y');
data.addColumn('number','Theoretical Value for z');
```

Thanks !

EDIT : I've just put my code in JSFiddle if anyone has an idea ..
Here is the link :
http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/1295/#&togetherjs=2eScOQJzki

Comment: Which language is that ? Javascript ? Please tag your question with the correct language.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, it's Javascript, I'll add the tag !

Comment: I've added the link to JSfiddle if anybody can help me ..